# How to fix the header in table scroll in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a html in which the contents get added dynamically. i would like to scroll the contents in the table and make the header to be fixed while scrolling but when i used the scroll the header also scrolls can any one tell me what i have to do to make the header to be fixed while scrolling the contents.

```
<div class="tableContainer" ng-style="{ 'overflow' : 'auto', 'max-height' : vm.height }">
        <table class="ledgerTable" cellspacing="10">
          <thead fix-head>
              <tr class="ledgerTblHeader">
              <th>{{"serialnumber_message" | translate}}</th>
              <th>{{"producttype_message" | translate}}</th>
              <!-- <th>{{"PC" | translate}}</th> -->
              <th>{{"count_message" | translate}}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="producttype in vm.vehicle.productdetails" ng-click="vm.showPopup(producttype)">
                <td>#{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{ producttype.type }}</td>
                <!-- <td>{{ ledger.other_amount }}</td> -->
                <td align="right">{{ producttype.count }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: See example https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Comment: Did you try table thead {position:fixed;} ?

Comment: you can create separate table for header and use same td width for both the tables

Comment: use this jquery plugin http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
    width: 500px;
}
th{
  background-color:green;
}
.scroll {
    max-height: 170px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head2</th>
    <th>head3</th>
    <th>head4</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="scroll">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        <td>Test Test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Might Help you.

Comment: In this way header and body table will get same width even td has more content

Comment: wait i'm updating

Comment: Updated Please Check